# Ansible - Zabbix - Inventory host hostname ipaddress - error

Tags: ip-address, ansible, hostname, inventory

Ansible 1.9.2 / 1.9.4

CentOS 6.7

I'm trying to find the IP address of a given hostname which is stored in the inventory file. If you see the my playbook, I got the IP of the hostname which I'm trying to find (see the first -debug section) but that's when I used "with_items" and passed "{{ groups['zabbix_server'] }}" as an item.

But now I'm trying to find the IP without using the hostname[**item**].... way i.e. directly using groups['zabbix_server'] way. How can I get the IP address of the host which is listed in hosts inventory file under zabbix_server **directly**? i.e. without using "with_items" line/feature in Ansible.

What I'm missing here to get these errors. I tried some online similar blogs/posts but those didn't help. Using [].[] or ['something].['somethingelse'] way didn't help either and for that I get:

*Failed to template msg="IP is= {{ hostvars[groups['zabbix_server']].[ansible_default_ipv4.address] }}": template error while templating string: expected name or number*

or
If I use this way:

```
IP is= {{ hostvars[groups['zabbix_server']]['ansible_default_ipv4']['address'] }}"
```

I get this error:

> ... *=> One or more undefined variables: 'HostVars' object has no element ['zabbix.dev-white.projectname.jenkins]*

Inventory file **hosts** contains:

```
[zabbix_server]
zabbix.dev-white.projectname.jenkins
```

My playbook file contains:

```
- debug: msg="Zabbix server= {{ item }} and its IP is= {{ hostvars[item].ansible_default_ipv4.address }}"
  with_items:
    - "{{ groups['zabbix_server'] }}"
  tags:
    - lilupandut

- debug: msg="Zabbix server= {{ item }} and its IP is= {{ hostvars[groups['zabbix_server']][ansible_default_ipv4.address] }}"
  with_items:
    - "{{ groups['zabbix_server'] }}"
  tags:
    - lilupandut

#- debug: msg="Zabbix server= {{ item }} and its IP is= {{ groups['zabbix_server'][ansible_default_ipv4.address] }}"
#  with_items:
#    - "{{ groups['zabbix_server'] }}"
#  tags:
#    - lilupandut
```

If I run the above playbook, I get the following output (valid output from the first -debug section) and an error (for the 2nd -debug section where I'm trying to use direct way of getting to the IP address i.e. *not using hostvars[item]*).

```
$ ansible-playbook zabbix-setup.yml -i hosts -u koba --private-key ${DEPLOYER_KEY_FILE} -t lilupandut

PLAY [zabbix_server] **********************************************************

GATHERING FACTS ***************************************************************
ok: [zabbix.dev-white.projectname.jenkins]

TASK: [zabbix_install | debug msg="Zabbix server= {{ item }} and its IP is= {{ hostvars[item].ansible_default_ipv4.address }}"] ***
ok: [zabbix.dev-white.projectname.jenkins] => (item=zabbix.dev-white.projectname.jenkins) => {
    "item": "zabbix.dev-white.projectname.jenkins",
    "msg": "Zabbix server= zabbix.dev-white.projectname.jenkins and its IP is= 10.130.64.18"
}

TASK: [zabbix_install | debug msg="Zabbix server= {{ item }} and its IP is= {{ groups['zabbix_server'][ansible_default_ipv4.address] }}"] ***
fatal: [zabbix.dev-white.projectname.jenkins] => One or more undefined variables: 'HostVars' object has no element [zabbix.dev-white.projectname.jenkins]

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting
```

If I **comment** out the middle -debug section and **un-comment** the last -debug statement, then I get close to what I'm looking for "IP address" but it still error out.

This time the error / output comes as:

```
projectname: [zabbix_install | debug msg="Zabbix server= {{ item }} and its IP is= {{ groups['zabbix_server'][ansible_default_ipv4.address] }}"] ***
fatal: [zabbix.dev-white.projectname.jenkins] => One or more undefined variables: 'list' object has no attribute '10.130.64.18'

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************
           to retry, use: --limit @/home/confman/zabbix-setup.retry

zabbix.dev-white.projectname.jenkins : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear to my why you do not want to use the `item` of the list you use. All your examples have the `with_items` loop, so you also can use `item` in all examples-

Let's have a look at this task of yours:

```
- debug: msg="Zabbix server= {{ item }} and its IP is= {{ hostvars[groups['zabbix_server']][ansible_default_ipv4.address] }}"
  with_items:
    - "{{ groups['zabbix_server'] }}"
  tags:
    - lilupandut
```

So you're looping over `groups['zabbix_server']` which is a list of hosts. `item` then would refer to each item of that list. What is the point of not using `item` in this case then, where you're looping over a list?

In your task then you attempt to use `hostvars[groups['zabbix_server']][ansible_default_ipv4.address]`. `hostvars` is a hash, `groups['zabbix_server']` is a list. You can not use a list as an hash key and that is why you get an error like this:

> I get this error: ... => One or more undefined variables: 'HostVars' object has no element ['zabbix.dev-white.projectname.jenkins]

As the error message attempts to explain, it is trying to look up a hash element with the key `['zabbix.dev-white.projectname.jenkins']`.

So as said, it's not really clear to me what you try to archive. Using `item` would be the way to get to the correct element of the loop.

```
hostvars[item]
```

Because `item` holds the value `zabbix.dev-white.projectname.jenkins`.

If you'd have no loop involved at all you could use the first host of the `zabbix_server` group like this:

```
hostvars[groups['zabbix_server'][0]]
```

In words again: `groups['zabbix_server']` is a list `[0]` accesses the first item of that list. But if you're in a loop anyway, there is actually no point in doing this.

```
hostvars[groups['zabbix_server'][0]]['ansible_default_ipv4']['address']
```

is the same as

```
hostvars[item]['ansible_default_ipv4']['address']
```

Comment: In my case, initially I thought I have to use with_items with with_dict but later thought to use only with_items. In my answer, I found using [0] was the way as you mentioned and agree that your explanation is better :). Thanks. One other thing, I'm trying to find the domain of my server using ansible_domain or facter_domain but they both don't work. Running ansible -m setup localhost shows them with value values. Any ideas?

Comment: `ansible_domain` should work, if your host is configured correctly with its hostname. It basically reads the fqdn of the host splits by `.` and removes the first element. So `zabbix.dev-white.projectname.jenkins` would be in the domain `dev-white.projectname.jenkins`. Is this not what you want or does it not work that way for you?

Comment: When I'm running ansible -m setup -i hosts zabbix_server, it gives me output where both ansible_domain and facter_domain have valid value of the server's domain i.e. dev-white.projectname.jenkins. But, then I'm running -debug: msg="My server is = {{ hostvars[groups['zabbix_server'][0]].inventory_hostname }} ---and--- domain is = {{ hostvars[groups['zabbix_server'][0]].ansible_domain }}", it works for showing the server name (fqdn) correctly but value for .ansible_domain or .facter_domain is coming as ' ' (blank), it's not populated.

Comment: and btw, the hosts inventory file doesn't set ansible_ssh_host=x.x.x.x (as I found this is going to be deprecated soon). My inventory just uses [zabbix_server] and in the next line zabbix.dev-white.projectname.jenkins (as mentioned in the post).

Comment: Try `{{ hostvars[groups['zabbix_server'][0]]['inventory_hostname'] }}`

Comment: that part works as I mentioned but it'll show the fqdn value of the server (as it's .inventory_hostname) its value is coming as zabbix.dev-white.projectname.jenkins. I just want "dev-white.projectname.jenkins" domain part only. I tried to set ansible_ssh_host=10.130.64.18 and re-ran the playbook and it still didn't show the domain part with {{ hostvars[groups['zabbix_server'][0]]['ansible_domain'] }}

Comment: Err sorry, yes, I meant `ansible_domain`, not `inventory_hostname`. But my point was the format `['ansible_domain']` vs `.ansible_domain`. But it looks like you tried that and it doesn't work either. Maybe you start a new question for that problem. It quickly gets unreadable here in the comments.

Comment: Oh, one last idea... is the zabix server actually part of the current play? I mean, are any tasks run on that host or do you target another group of the inventory? If no tasks are ran on the zabix hosts, the setup module never is executed and therefore you do not have any host facts available. Might that be the problem?

Comment: Sure, I'll open a new question. Zabbix server is sitting in file "hosts" and zabbix_setup.yml says hosts: zabbix_server (where zabbix_server is a group in hosts inventory file and contains zabbix.dev-white.projectname.jenkins as its value). The Gathering Facts piece shows it's succeessful. I'm trying to understand your last comment's statement about no tasks ran on zabbix host... it might be the reason which is not populating the fact variables.

Answer (score 0):

Come on Ansible!! -- I need to watch these more carefully.

I guess the following error helped me with the hint. The value in hostvars[item] variable (when passed via with_items: "{{ groups['zabbix_server'] }}" was coming as a type of LIST variable.

**'HostVars' object has no element ['zabbix.dev-white.projectname.jenkins']**

My main aim was to change zabbix_agent's conf file for two variables: Server=x.x.x.x and ServerActive=zabbix.server.with.fqdn  **without** hardcoding the zabbix server **and without** creating extra variables in the role's default/main.yml file for storing zabbix server's hostname(fqdn) and it's IP address.

I wanted to use the inventory file (as per my post) and pick whatever [zabbix_server] group contained in it.

The solution was to use **[0]** to tell Ansible hostvars to pick the first element from the returned LIST variable while using either **hostvars[item]** or using the **direct** way (i.e. groups['zabbix_server']).

The following sections uses with_items.

In the first section, I'm using hostvars[item.three[0]]..... and it worked to show the IP address of the zabbix server.

The second section, where even though I'm using with_items, I'm NOT using the item.three variable ...as I'm using hostvars[groups[....[0]].... way (directly) and it worked too.

Enjoy.

```
- debug: msg="1 -- Zabbix server= {{ item.three }} and its IP is= {{ hostvars[item.three[0]].ansible_default_ipv4.address }}"
  with_items:
    - { one: "1", two: "two 22", three: "{{ groups['zabbix_server'] }}" }
  tags:
    - lilupandut

- debug: msg="2 -- Zabbix server= {{ item.three }} and its IP is= {{ hostvars[groups['zabbix_server'][0]].ansible_default_ipv4.address }}"
  with_items:
    - { one: "1", two: "two 22", three: "{{ groups['zabbix_server'] }}" }
  tags:
    - lilupandut
```

OR 
simply, you can say: The following will work.

```
- debug: msg="3 -- Zabbix server= {{ inventory_hostname }} and its IP is= {{ hostvars[groups['zabbix_server'][0]].ansible_default_ipv4.address }}"
  tags:
    - lilupandut
```